# asp.net change format on various fields with same prefix, different suffix

Tags: asp.net, loops, webforms, findcontrol

I have the following VB code in an asp.net page.

It works fine, however I am sure there must be a better way (one only line perhaps) to cover all 6 fields within the block.

As you can see there are 4 rows of fields, each row contains 6 fields.
Their ID all start with prefix "txtDO", then a number (7 to 11), then a suffix (_D, _C, _1, _2, _3, _B)

Note that these are not the only fields on the page, there are several groups.
Since I have also additional code running within the VB loop, I need to keep it this way.

```
For l = 7 To 11                   
                CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & "_D"), TextBox).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
                CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & "_C"), TextBox).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
                CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & "_1"), TextBox).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
                CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & "_2"), TextBox).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
                CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & "_3"), TextBox).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
                CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & "_B"), TextBox).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
            Next l
```

I am looking for something like this, see the suffix * which covers ALL fields, therefore only one line of code instead of 6.

```
CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & "*"), TextBox).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a nested Foreach loop...

```
Dim letters() As String = {"_D", "_C", "_1", "_2", "_3", "_B"}
For l = 7 To 11 
    For Each letter As String In letters                   
        CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & letter).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
    Next
Next l
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use a nested foreach loop as I didn't know I could do that. Now I do. Fantastic!, although not the code I was after, this shortens my routine by at least 50% and makes the whole thing simpler and more logical. By the way, your code gave an error, but this works (was missing the, Textbox) part: CType(FindControl("txtDO" & l & letter), TextBox).Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do it with one line of code, with one FindControl like you are asking.
FindControl returns only one control to work with.
See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation for more details.